# How to write the SWIG interface file?

Tags: c++, swig

For example, I have `test.cpp`:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void hello(){
    cout<<"Hello World!"<<endl;
}
```

I write `test.i`:

```
%module test

%{
#include<iostream>
%}

void hello();
```

When I compile test_wrap.cxx, it tell me `hello() is not declare`, and I change `test.i` to:

```
%module test

%{
#include<iostream>
void hello();
%}

void hello();
```

It pass the compiling, I'm confused because I see some [demos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360884/how-to-create-swig-interface-file) don't write function declaration in `%{` `%{`, and why we need to write 
`void hello();` twice?

Comment: Instead of declaring functions in the interface file manually, you are [encouraged](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIG_nn46) to `%include` your header file. Doesn’t it work for you?

Answer (score 3):

The code between `%{` and `%}` is copied directly into the generated wrapper.  The wrapper needs to know that `void hello();` is external.

The code outside the `%{` and `%}` markers generates wrapper code, so `void hello();` generates wrapper code for the function.

To avoid the repetition you can use:

```
%inline %{
    void hello();
%}
```

This both adds the code to the wrapper and generates the wrappers.

Comment: What do you mean `wrapper` and `generates the wrappers`?

Comment: Running SWIG generates source code that that wraps C++ functions in code that exposes the functions in a format another language can call.